# How can I find out via foursquare explorer who the owner (or manager?) of a venue is?

Tags: foursquare

how can I find out via foursquare explorer who the owner (or manager?) of a venue is?

I actually had my app working but now it doesn't, I'm not sure what changed but I doubt it was my php code.  I was able to save access tokens, venueids etc and send shouts to a page via curl calls to 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/pageupdates/add'.  Maybe I am using a different user account than before, maybe the old one was  a manager or owner of the venue. Now when I send a shout I get :

```
Array ( [meta] => Array ( [code] => 403 [errorType] => not_authorized [errorDetail] => Invalid page ) [response] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot, in general, get the manager of a venue from the API. You can see the list of venues that you manage with the `/venues/managed` endpoint.

Comment: Thanks,
According to the API Explorer my account does not manage anything, even though I claimed the listing with the same account and when I click the "Claim it now" link it takes me to a page saying that I am done and have claimed it, that page has a "lets get started" button and when I click it i get a page saying "We couldn't find the page you're looking for.".    Also I do not get the manager tools toolbar when logged in.  So  am I stuck unable to test off that listing?  ( I want to send shouts ).  (continued...)

Comment: (continued) This is very odd since I had previously done just that many times successfully and am only returning to this app now to tweak the authorization UI and not the actual app function.

Comment: Turned out my account was somehow messed up, the foursquare techies had to reset something on their end to fix it, now I  see the manager tools.